# Download CSV file from website that changes name every month

Tags: r

pretty new to R and just trying to get my head round web scrapping.

So I want to download into R a CSV file (easy enough I can do that). The issue that i am having is that every month the CSV file name changes on the website, so the URL then also changes.

So is there a way in R to tell it to download the the CSV file  without the exact file url?

here is the website i am practicing it on:

https://www.police.uk/pu/your-area/police-scotland/performance/999-data-performance/

Thanks :)

So tried the basic stuff like below, issue is the url will change when the file is updated.

```
dat <- read.csv(
  "https://www.police.uk/contentassets/069a2c11fcb444bbbeb519f69875577e/2022/sept/999-data-nov-21---sep-22.csv"
  , header = T)
```

view(dat)

Comment: There's no way to do this. Not just in R, but fundamentally. What you *can* do is crawl the website to find out the name of the current file (e.g. using ‘rvest’ or ‘RSelenium’). However, the website you linked to specifically does not seem to allow this, and has measures in place to prevent it. This is a shame (especially since this kind of data should be publicly accessible), but unfortunately fairly common.

Comment: If you can use Google or other search engine w/ an API to search for all " $NAME.csv" , restricting the search to the base URL , you should be able to parse the results to get the filename & path you want.